# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z\ expicitly on Jboss EAP 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, jboss-eap-7

I am relatively new to spring ,I am facing jackson data bind error while deploying the war to Jboss EAP 7 but when i deploy the same war on wildfly 10 its deploying successfully .I have added Moxy but its not helping on Jboss
**Jboss Log**

> "{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\\"/gamification-1.0.0\\"\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\\"/gamification-1.0.0\\": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
>       Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z\"}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know It has passed many days just Answering if someone else got the problem.
What i did was just Excluded Rest Easy Implementation from Jboss by Adding the Following Config File ,So it wont clash with Jersey config

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After including that Issue Was resolved